# Recoding malloc - Cannot return memory

Tags: c, unix, return, malloc, mmap

I have to recode the function malloc (3) in C.
I must use mmap() syscall in order to allocate pages.

I already made some versions, but, since it was not working, I decided to make a small and quick version, in a single function in order to debug.

Here is how I compile my testing program with my malloc :
`gcc unit_test.c libft/libft.a -L. -lft_malloc`
And here is how my makefile compile my malloc.so :
`gcc -g -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o libft_malloc.so srcs/malloc.c srcs/debug.c`

My unit_test.c program is very simple, I want to malloc a string of size 10, set all of its char at 'a', then print it :

```
#include "libft/libft.h"
#include "incs/malloc.h"

int         main(void)
{
    ft_putstr_fd("TEST 01\n", 2);
    char    *str;
    int     i;

    str = NULL;
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (!str)
    {
        ft_putstr_fd("MALLOC FAILED\n", 2);
        return (-1);
    }

    ft_putstr_fd("MALLOC SUCCESS\n", 2);
    i = 0;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        str[i] = 'a';
        i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    ft_putchar_fd('\n', 2);
    ft_putstr_fd(str, 2);
    ft_putchar_fd('\n', 2);
    return (0);
}
```

No problem though. It should work (it does with the real malloc).

Here is how my 'block' struct is :

```
typedef struct          s_block
{
    size_t              size;
    char                *memory;
    struct s_block      *next;
    struct s_block      *prev;
}                       t_block;
```

size is the size of the memory asked, memory is a pointer to the first address of the memory I want to return (I casted it to a char *), next and prev as this is a linked list.

Finally, this is my malloc function :

```
void        *malloc(size_t size)
{
    char        *memory;
    t_block     *block;
    int         i;
    size_t      total_size;

    memory = NULL;
    i = 0;

    total_size = size + sizeof(t_block);

    while (total_size % 16)    // Align memory
        total_size++;

    memory = mmap(0, total_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    while (i < total_size)
    {
        memory[i] = 'z';
        i++;
    }
        db_putstr_fd("Printing memory...\n", 2);
        db_putstr_fd(memory, 2);
        db_putchar_fd('\n', 2);
    block = (t_block *)&memory;
    block->size = size;
    block->next = NULL;
    block->prev = NULL;
        db_putstr_fd("Block size = ", 2);
        db_putnbr_fd(block->size, 2);
        db_putchar_fd('\n', 2);
    block->memory = (char *)&block + sizeof(t_block);
    i = 0;
    while (i < block->size)
    {
            db_putstr_fd("i = ", 2);
            db_putnbr_fd(i, 2);
            db_putstr_fd("\tsize = ", 2);
            db_putnbr_fd(block->size, 2);
            db_putchar_fd('\n', 2);
        block->memory[i] = 'a';
        i++;
    }

        db_putstr_fd("Out of loop\n", 2);
        db_putstr_fd(block->memory, 2);
        db_putchar_fd('\n', 2);

    return (block->memory);
}
```

So, I mmap a char *memory (will be replaced by pages when I will be sure this will working). I set my block to the beginning of this memory, and then I init all of my block structs variables.
My problem might be when I set the string address of the block.
I voluntarily indented my debug lines, as they are numerous, so you can better see the interesting lines ; but I decided to keep them to show you the result :

```
TEST 01
Printing memory...
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Block size = 10
i = 0   size = 10
i = 1   size = 10
i = 2   size = 10
i = 3   size = 10
i = 4   size = 10
i = 5   size = 10
i = 6   size = 10
i = 7   size = 10
i = 8   size = 10
i = 9   size = 10
Out of loop
aaaaaaaaaa
[1]    59894 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

As you can see, I can write inside the memory in my malloc, but then when I return it, the program segfault. I think it happens on line 11 of my unit_test.c file, but why?

How can I write in the memory string in malloc function, but then can't return it to the program that called malloc?
Am I missing somethin ?

Comment: You mmap *every single* call to malloc. Everything you do after mmap—blocks, linked lists, the works—all of it makes no sense whatsoever. The next call to malloc will see none of that. It will get its own fresh memory page. You could have just return what mmap returns and call it a day (free would just call munmap). This would work but it kinda defeats the purpose of the entire exercise.

Comment: `block = (t_block *)&memory; block->size = size;` is blatantly invalid. `block` is pointing to `memory`, a local variable (of size 8 bytes). You can't store a whole `t_block` in that.

Comment: @n.m. I know about that, my previous versions were using mmap to create a structure t_page, which were containing a list of blocks, a type, a size, etc.  Here I just wanted to test, that's why I only used mmap to allocate a block.

Comment: @melpomene Is'nt memory pointing on a memory address that I allocated with mmap ? Then how should I store my allocated memory ? In my previous tests, I used a linked list of pages as global variables.

Comment: @Elynad It doesn't matter where `memory` is pointing. That code doesn't use `memory`'s value. You could've done `double memory; block = (t_block *)&memory;` and get pretty much the same effect.

Comment: I see. You are taking addresses of local variables `memory` and `block`. These addresses are invalid outside of the current call to `malloc`, so storing them or anything calculated from them inside your block cannot possibly be right.

Comment: By Odin's beard, @n.m. you are a god.
I set my *memory in my .h file as a global variable, and it worked. Thank you !
I just have to understand why it did not work in my previous versions, where I was using pages as global variables, with blocks and memory inside it.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Wow, so now you're scribbling over unrelated global variables in the data section. Have you considered fixing your code instead?

Comment: PS: The crux of your problem seems to be that you don't understand the difference between `a = b` and `a = &b`.

Comment: Right, I just wanted to test if I could print memory casted to chars.
@melpomene you are right, I still have to learn about pointers. The thing is, I did not code in C since a long time, I feel like I forgot some basics about it.
I am fixing my code, btw :)